# System.InvalidCastException when binding Stacklayout BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector to MVVM Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have used a ListView where I used a `Itemtemplate` and used x2 viewcell pages, but due to bad performance in this listview, I am trying to adjust it to a bindable StackLayout instead, which I have had much better experiences with (wrapped in a scrollview) lately, especially for Android.

With my ListView it works well, but now when I try to adjust that working code to a stacklayout instead I get the exception:

`System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at Xamarin.Forms.BindableLayoutController.CreateItemView`

My xaml looks like this:

```
             <ScrollView>

                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding chatService.Messages}"
                             BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}"
                             x:Name="ChatList"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding RowSelected}"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>

            </ScrollView>
```

My `MessageTemplateSelector` like this:

```
    private readonly DataTemplate incomingDataTemplate;
    private readonly DataTemplate outgoingDataTemplate;

    public MyDataTemplateSelector()
    {
        // Retain instances!
        this.incomingDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(IncomingGridView));
        this.outgoingDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(OutGoingGridView));
    }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        var messageVm = item as Message;
        if (messageVm == null)
            return null;

        return messageVm.IsIncoming ? this.incomingDataTemplate : this.outgoingDataTemplate;
    }
```

So here I have x2 different grid pages (instead of x2 viewcell pages that i used with the listview), IncomingGridView and OutGoingGridView. These pages are regular Grid views, with just a backgroundcolor, so nothing special.

So what am I doing wrong when trying to take advantage of the `ItemTemplateSelector` of the Stacklayout?

Comment: Are your `IncomingGridView` or `OutgoingGridView` still inside `ViewCells`? ListView uses ViewCells but BindableLayout does not. That could throw the exception

Comment: No, both of them are `Grid`s

Comment: `public partial class OutGoingViewCell : Grid` with a regular XAML inside.

Comment: @DiddanDo Hi , could you share a sample project link here , I will check that .